# PHPEXCEL getCell() get datetime to string

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have made an online survey using google doc. I want to automate the calculation of the results using PHPEXCEL. Why is it that when I used `getCell("A2")` which should have returned `09/05/2017  4:33:43 PM` returns `42864.690079606` How do I get the `09/05/2017  4:33:43 PM` so that I can be able to assign it to a variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this function :

```
PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::toFormattedString($yourCell->getCalculatedValue(), 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
```